# How is ActiveSupport::SecureRandom secure?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random, security

Is the `ActiveSupport::SecureRandom` secure in the way that it is 'impossible' to figure out random numbers or is it secure in the way that it will return UUIDs?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The security of the random number (and its application) comes from how sufficiently random it is for cryptographic purposes. The quality of the randomness relies to a great extent on the entropy that the system can provide such as through interfaces like `/dev/urandom` on Linux. For it to be secure, an attacker must not be able to guess the next random number, given some sequence of previously generated random numbers.

You could use ActiveRecord::SecureRandom as part of an implementation for creating [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_Unique_Identifier) (version 4) but they are not directly related

Comment: As far as I can tell, SecureRandom does *not* use Mersenne Twister.  That's fortunate, because (contrary to what bjg wrote), Mersenne Twister is *not* cryptographically secure and *not* adequate for security purposes.

Comment: @D.W. is correct SecureRandom does _not_ use MT.  It depends on what platform it runs on, http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/securerandom_rb.html